# Маска ввода в type="text"

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

В БД имеется поле с типом date. Т.е. данные вводятся туда в таком формате: 2010-10-10.
Имеется поле `<input type="text" name="date_vipis" id="date_v" />`, в которую и вводится дата. Как задать маску ввода, чтоб данные поступали в БД не 2010.10.10 или 10.10.2010 а именно в формате доступном для БД? Как выполнить проверку на яваскрипт, что поле заполнено верно? JQuery применять не желательно. Нужна именно яваскрипт и php.
Может быть, возможно изменить формат хранения в типе data в бд? Если да, то как? Но основной вопрос с проверкой заполнения поля.

Answer (score 4):

Вариантов несколько:

- первый это - input заменить на 3 select, в которых в нужном порядке выставить год, месяц, число. Далее полученные данные собрать в дату в нужном формате, предварительно, разумеется, проверив их в php на правильность;
- второй - ковырять javascript, например, отсюда ([валидация даты](http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/date_validation.asp)) и точно также потом проверить их в php на правильность.

Ведь никто не гарантирует, что вашу форму отправят к вам на сервер именно вашим скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

форматирование ввода легко делается с помощью jquery. Есть только минус в том, что (а это редко, но бывает) js у некоторых отключен и придётся дополнительно проверять данные на сервере. Может лучше просто проверять на сервере и не делать лишнюю работу?!

Comment: Данные от пользователя на сервере надо проверять ВСЕГДА, и не надеяться ни на флеш, ни на JavaScript!

Comment: @GLAGOLA, следишь за мной?! ))))

Answer (score 0):

В JS Date Validation смысла не вижу. ИМХО, лучше через [Masked Input Plugin](http://www.netopalto.ru/masked-input-plugin/) для jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

можно еще задать маску:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="YYYY-MM-DD">
```

при таком заполнении будет в поле ввода автоматически ставиться YYYY-MM-DD
А уж там додуматься где YYYY-год MM-месяц DD-день можно

Answer (score 0):

В обработчике на сервере

в посте приходит введенная строка с датой. Формат даты можешь ставить свой.

```
$mydate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['date']));
```